# complete elliptic integral of the first kind

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, elliptic-integrals

I'm looking for any "closed form" for the coefficient of the $\ell$-th power of $K(x)$, the complete elliptic integral of the first kind.

Thanks.

Comment: Does (2) from [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteEllipticIntegraloftheFirstKind.html) help you? [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral) also has something to tell :$K(k) = \frac{\pi}{2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left[\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2 n} (n!)^2}\right]^2 k^{2n} = \frac{\pi}{2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty [P_{2 n}(0)]^2 k^{2n}$.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have this expression and I look for the l-th power. I have found a connexion with the Dedekind eta function for which l-th powers are well studied...let see...;o)). Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Since the user seems to have not come back, I'll just leave this around:

Letting

$$K(m)=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\mathrm du}{\sqrt{1-m\sin^2 u}}$$

be the complete elliptic integral of the first kind with parameter $m$, we have the corresponding hypergeometric series expansion

$$K(m)=\frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{j=0}^\infty \binom{2k}{k}^2\left(\frac{m}{16}\right)^k$$

As always, if one wants the coefficients of $\left(\dfrac2{\pi}K(m)\right)^\ell$, the usual recourse is the [Faà di Bruno formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula). One especially convenient form makes use of the [partial Bell polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials#Fa.C3.A0_di_Bruno.27s_formula):

$$\left(\frac2{\pi}K(m)\right)^\ell=1+\sum_{j=1}^\infty \mathcal K_j m^j$$

where

$$\mathcal K_j=\frac1{j!}\sum_{r=1}^j r!\binom{\ell}{r} B_{j,r}\left(\frac14,\frac9{32},\cdots,\frac{(j-r+1)!}{16^{j-r+1}}\binom{2(j-r+1)}{j-r+1}^2\right)$$

There may be simpler expressions for $\mathcal K_j$, but I don't know them.

---

The convenience of the Bell polynomial formulation of the Faà di Bruno formula lies in the fact that computing environments like *Mathematica* explicitly support the partial Bell polynomials. As a demonstration:

```
With[{l = 5}, CoefficientList[Series[(2EllipticK[m]/Pi)^l,{m, 0, 6}],m]]
{1, 5/4, 85/64, 345/256, 22005/16384, 87009/65536, 1370745/1048576}

With[{l = 5}, Prepend[Table[
     Sum[k! Binomial[l, k] BellY[n, k,
              Table[j! Binomial[2 j, j]^2/16^j, {j, 1, n - k + 1}]],
         {k, 1, n}]/n!, {n, 1, 6}], 1]]
{1, 5/4, 85/64, 345/256, 22005/16384, 87009/65536, 1370745/1048576}
```

Comment: (1) Feng Qi, Chao-Ping Chen, and Dongkyu Lim, Several identities containing central binomial coefficients and derived from series expansions of powers of the arcsine function, Results in Nonlinear Analysis 4 (2021), no. 1, 57--64; available online at https://doi.org/10.53006/rna.867047. (2) Bai-Ni Guo, Dongkyu Lim, and Feng Qi, Series expansions of powers of arcsine, closed forms for special values of Bell polynomials, and series representations of generalized logsine functions, AIMS Mathematics 6 (2021), no. 7, 7494--7517; available online at https://doi.org/10.3934/math.2021438.

Answer (score 0):

According to Maple 16:

> FunctionAdvisor(sum_form,EllipticK(x));

$$[{\it EllipticK} \left( x \right) =\sum _{{\it \_n1}=0}^{\infty }1/2\,
{\frac {\pi \, \left( {\it pochhammer} \left( 1/2,{\it \_n1} \right) 
 \right) ^{2}{x}^{2\,{\it \_n1}}}{ \left( {\it \_n1}! \right) ^{2}}},{
\it And} \left(  \left| x \right| <1,x\neq 0 \right) ]
$$
$$[{\it EllipticK} \left( x \right) =\sum _{{\it \_n1}=0}^{\infty }{
\frac { \left( {\it pochhammer} \left( 1/2,{\it \_n1} \right) 
 \right) ^{2} \left( 1/2\,\ln  \left( -{x}^{2} \right) +\Psi \left( 1+
{\it \_n1} \right) -\Psi \left( 1/2-{\it \_n1} \right)  \right) }{{x}^
{2\,{\it \_n1}} \left( {\it \_n1}! \right) ^{2}}}{\frac {1}{\sqrt {-{x
}^{2}}}},{\it And} \left( 1\leq  \left| x \right|  \right) ]
$$